Docker Angular Nginx can't connect to other service (netcore 8)
Angular 17.
When running services with docker-compose can't connect from nginx to other service (actually gateway with port 5000). After main page loads it starts to fetch data from gateway and I get an error for all requests.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/api/settings/background. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
Now I set Netcore8 services AllowAnyOrigins to true.
Use Docker default network - bridge - all services run inside that network - checked.
In NetCore containers use servers names setup in docker (not ip's)
Swagger for NetCore runs.
Dockerfile for Front is as follows:
#STAGE 1
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
EXPOSE 4200
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run ng -- build --configuration production
#STAGE 2
FROM nginx:alpine
EXPOSE 80
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/EZui /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

nginx.conf is
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'; 
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;  
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;        
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        gzip                    on;
        gzip_comp_level         9;
        gzip_vary               on;
        gzip_min_length         256;
        gzip_proxied            expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript  application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_buffers            16 8k;
        gunzip on;      
        client_max_body_size    256M;
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
            #proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            #proxy_buffering off;
            #proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        }
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;           
        }          
    }   
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;  
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

In angular I use environment.production
api = 'http://localhost:5000/api';

I tried to change localhost to names that are set for docker on front and back (for instance to gateway- that's the name of gateway Netcore service.
Tried to play with nginx.conf - added even location / settings:
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                #
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                #
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                #
                #add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
             }
             if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
             }
             if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
             }

also tried to add reverse_proxy to nginx.conf.
Still get the same error. Read a lot of issues and tried different fixes (many of them failed to run nginx) most of them in nginx.conf - nothing helped.
